# How to format a number so that it has a specific number of digits?

Tags: php

e.g., lets say I want `3` digits, then:

```
1 -> 1.00
10 -> 10.0
100 -> 100
1000 -> 1000 // don't lop off any numbers, as they're all significant
```

I thought I could do this via:

```
number_format($n, max(0,$digits-strlen((string)intval($n))), null, '')
```

which works for all the above cases, but it fails for `99.99` (giving `100.0` instead of `100`).

So I'm not quite sure how to do this. Counting the number of digits before the decimal place won't work because it may change after rounding.

N.B. when I say "digits" I mean the total number of digits, before *and* after the decimal place. Also note that this is not quite the same as "significant figures", as I count "1000" as "4 digits", which is "1 significant figure" and "0 decimal digits".

Comment: @Dagon I'm not sure how I can do it without first testing if rounding will add another digit, but yeah, I'm sure I can come up with something.

Comment: @PaulCrovella Yeah, this question is about formatting. Rounding should only occur when there are decimals and they can't fit within the allotted number of digits.

Comment: This isn't about rounding is it? Because for rounding you have nice functions that do rounding perfectly well. What exactly is your goal?

Comment: @markus The `round` function accepts a number of *decimal* digits to round to (i.e., digits after the decimal place). I basically want the same function but it should include the whole numbers in "digits".

Comment: Well, it's still not called rounding when you add digits to a number. Adding `.00` to `1` is also false precision if that information wasn't available before. So again, what are you doing and why?

Comment: @markus Okay, then I'm "formatting" a number. Do I need a reason? I have numbers and I want them to be roughly the same size visually. More specifically, I'm formatting file sizes. Precision addition/loss is not a concern; this isn't scientific :-)

Comment: Good, now you're using the right language which means people can help and now how to help.

Answer (score 1):

try below

```
number_format($n, max(0,$digits-strlen((string) ( (strlen(str_replace('.','',(string)$n))<=$digits) ? intval($n) : (max(round($n),intval($n))) ))), null, '');

php > $n=1;
php > print number_format($n, max(0,$digits-strlen((string) ( (strlen(str_replace('.','',(string)$n))<=$digits) ? intval($n) : (max(round($n),intval($n))) ))), null, '');
1.00
php > $n=10;
php > print number_format($n, max(0,$digits-strlen((string) ( (strlen(str_replace('.','',(string)$n))<=$digits) ? intval($n) : (max(round($n),intval($n))) ))), null, '');
10.0
php > $n=100;                                                                                                                                                           
php > print number_format($n, max(0,$digits-strlen((string) ( (strlen(str_replace('.','',(string)$n))<=$digits) ? intval($n) : (max(round($n),intval($n))) ))), null, '');
100
php > $n=1000;                                                                                                                                                          
php > print number_format($n, max(0,$digits-strlen((string) ( (strlen(str_replace('.','',(string)$n))<=$digits) ? intval($n) : (max(round($n),intval($n))) ))), null, '');
1000
php > $n=99.99;
php > print number_format($n, max(0,$digits-strlen((string) ( (strlen(str_replace('.','',(string)$n))<=$digits) ? intval($n) : (max(round($n),intval($n))) ))), null, '');
100
php > $n=99.9;
php > print number_format($n, max(0,$digits-strlen((string) ( (strlen(str_replace('.','',(string)$n))<=$digits) ? intval($n) : (max(round($n),intval($n))) ))), null, '');
99.9
```

Comment: Fails for `99.9`. Should yield `99.9` but because you didn't include any args to `round`, it yields `100`.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something. Here's the gist of it:

```
function _whole_digit_count($n) {
    return strlen(abs((int)$n));
}

function _does_round_up($n, $d) {
    return _whole_digit_count(number_format($n, $d, null, '')) > _whole_digit_count($n);
}

function round_digits($size, $digits=3) {
     $wd = _whole_digit_count($size);
     $decimals = $digits - $wd;
     if($decimals > 0) {
        if(_does_round_up($size, $decimals)) {
            --$decimals;
        }
     }

     return number_format($size, $decimals, null, '')
}
```

Basically, we're using `number_format` here to do the rounding and add the 0s, but we first have to compute how many decimal places we want. We do that by subtracting off the number of digits to the left of the decimal place.

However, this may cause rounding up such that another digit is added to the whole number. In this scenario we have to subtract off an additional decimal place.